# Time Machine failing (.inProgress)

Tags: backup, time-machine

My Time Machine recently stopped working. When it tries to create a backup, it quickly fails with the error:

> "Unable to complete backup. An error occurred while creating the
>   backup folder."

The drive has plenty of space and I have not updating my operating system. Actually, due to software compatibility issues, I'm still running 10.9.5. Everything I've found on google says to remove the .inProgress file, but when I try to delete it (drag it to Trash) I get this error:

> "The Finder can't complete the operation because some data in
>   "file.inProgress" can't be read or written. (Error code -36)"

I've tried tmutil delete and it returned the error "tmutil: delete requires root privileges." I don't even know what that means. Can someone give me another suggestion? Manually backing up my hardrive is a huge pain and I forget to do it more often than not.

Comment: With regard to the problem with ‘tmutil delete’, you need to be superuser to delete backups, so prepend the command with ‘sudo’, as in `sudo tmutil delete …` to be prompted for your password.

Answer (score 1):

The user account named ”root” is a superuser with read and write privileges to more areas of the system.

It is disabled by default since it can do a lots of irreparable damages, so use it with caution.

In Terminal use the `Sudo` to invoke that root user account, and you will be prompted to enter the password, which is usually your Administrator password. It is just a protection for some powerful commands making sure you want to do that by confirming it with password.

```
sudo tmutil delete …
```

Password: .....